# Finding table caption in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to automatically extract data from tables of a Word document. I do this by iterating over all tables in VBA. I.e.

```
For Each tbl In wdDoc.Tables
Next
```

Is it possible to find the caption for a given table? i.e. the document has
"Table 3:" and then the table.

Note that not all the tables in the document have got a caption and therefore the table numbers in captions are different than the document table enumeration.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, table captions are not actually associated with their tables through the Word Object Model.  When a table caption is created, it is just text placed in a separate Paragraph object.

**So, the short answer is that no, there is no *good* way to find the caption for a given table.**

I did write some code that may help you though.  It basically iterates through all Paragraph objects in the document and looks for the "Caption" style (alternatively, you could look for text formatted "Table #:", or whatever you'd like).  If the very next Paragraph contains tables, it places the text of the caption into the first cell of the first table found.

```
    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim lastParagraphWasCaption As Boolean
    Dim lastCaptionText As String
    lastParagraphWasCaption = False

    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If lastParagraphWasCaption And p.Range.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            p.Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = lastCaptionText
        End If

        If p.Range.Style = "Caption" Then
            lastParagraphWasCaption = True
            lastCaptionText = p.Range.Text
        Else
            lastParagraphWasCaption = False
        End If
    Next
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example of how you could tie together a caption with its table.  With that said, it is not a very reliable method and **I would not recommend using it unless you absolutely need to** because table captions could presumably not have the caption styling, or there could be caption styling on something that isn't a caption, etc.

Comment: Thanks (+1); this matches my expectations and fears... I'll have another look on what I'll do with this!

Comment: I did find some issues though. The for each also finds the paragraphs within a table. And some of my documents have 'caption style' within tables (nasty). I've filtered that out, but the paragraph-wise iteration is much slower than the table based iteration.

Comment: There may be a trick to do better:  Table1.Select() and then move up 1 with something like Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, this will put the cursor right above the table. However, it does not get me the paragraph before the table, which is what I'm looking for. Ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately paragraph iteration will of course always be slower because of the iteration of every single object in the document as opposed to just the tables. The basic premise of your idea was my first instinct too- iterating through tables and finding the previous paragraph (with caption formatting probably). If I have some time I will try to look into this.